# How to display data from a composable to a component Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, composable

I'm facing an issue with a Vuejs 3 composables. Trying to make a single composable for each of three inputs - the email type input and a text type inputs. I can't visualize the email typed in the button component template. Even though I'm importing the composable hook js file to the button the same way as to the input components. I just can't get how to get the input data to display it. The same kind of issue is how actually to send the collected inputs data to the parent component for submiting the form as I'm using the composable component itself. Could anyone help please?

**useInputComposable**

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'

export function useInput() {
 const input = ref('')
 let passed = ref('')
 
 function updateInput(newInput) {
   input.value = newInput
 }
 return [ input, updateInput ]
}
```

**Parent component**

```html
<template>
  <TextInput />
  <TextInput />
  <EmailInput />
  <Buttoncomponent />
</template>
```

**Text type input**

```js
<script setup>
import { useInput } from '@/composables/useInput.js'
const [input, updateInput] = useInput()
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <label for="input">{{ input }}</label>
    <input
      id="input"
      type="text"
      :value="input"
      @input="updateInput($event.target.value)"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

**Email type input**

```js
<script setup>
import { useInput } from '@/composables/useInput.js'
const [input, updateInput] = useInput()
</script>

<template>
  <div class="input">
    <input
      id="input"
      type="email"
      :value="input"
      @input="updateEmailInput($event.target.value)"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

**Button component**

```js
<script setup>
import { useInput } from '@/composables/useInput.js'
const [ input ] = useInput()
</script>

<template>
  <button>{{ input }} place the email here</button> <!-- the input is empty here ('') -->
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a composable here is unnecessary and more complicated than it should be. Change from using a composable to [v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html) to two-way bind data in child components to the parent component.  It's much more appropriate for what you're doing

**Parent component**

```js
<script setup>
import TextInput from './TextInput.vue';
import EmailInput from './EmailInput.vue';
import ButtonComponent from './ButtonComponent.vue';
import { ref } from 'vue'

const email = ref('')
const input1 = ref('')
const input2 = ref('')
</script>

<template>
  <TextInput v-model="input1" />
  <TextInput v-model="input2" />
  <EmailInput v-model="email" />
  <ButtonComponent :email="email" />
</template>
```

**TextInput**

```js
<script setup>
defineProps(['modelValue'])
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <label for="input">{{ modelValue }}</label>
    <input
      id="input"
      type="text"
      :value="modelValue"
      @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

**EmailInput**

```js
<script setup>
defineProps(['modelValue'])
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>

<template>
  <div class="input">
    <input
      id="input"
      type="email"
      :value="modelValue"
      @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

**ButtonComponent**

```js
<script setup>
defineProps(['email'])
</script>

<template>
  <button>{{ email }}</button>
</template>
```

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thanx fr sharing, it clears everything but my challenge here was to try do with composables. Is it actually possible to get the data from a single composable to a propriete one ?

Comment: Problem is trying to share composable state between multiple components.  `input` in ComponentA is unique from `input` in ComponentB.  How then do you set `input` in EmailInput and display that same value in ButtonComponent if the value isn't shared?  If you did turn `input` into a global state variable inside the composable, then `input` becomes the same for all components.  Updating `input` in EmailInput updates `input` in your TextInputs and vice versa, which is not what you want.  Composables are great, but they have limitations. You have to use the right tool for the job and this isnt it.